# Rounding corners of lines

Tags: graphics, rounding

I can easily produce rectangles with rounder corners using RoundingRadius. However, I am unable to do for an open curve

```
Graphics[Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}}]]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I want to generate the underlined part of the following rectangle:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.01], Black, Dashed}], 
FaceForm[GrayLevel[1]], 
Rectangle[{0., 0.}, {1, 1}, RoundingRadius -> .2]}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: maybe  [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve.html)?

Comment: How about CapForm? https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StylingLineCapsAndLineJoins/

Comment: @kglr BezierCurve curves too much. I have edited the question showing what I want.

Comment: You could place a white arc of a disk over the rounded rectangle to obscure the parts you don't want to see - but would that satisfy your requirements ?

Comment: So, 2 rounded corners and 2 edges? @MarkRobinson ?

Comment: @CATrevillian Yes!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I could make the desired diagram by joining circle and lines. However, I was wondering if there is a command to show only parts of a rectangle. Such commands for drawing arc of an circle is there!

Comment: You write that you want to show only part of *a rectangle*, but it looks as if you want to show only part of *the boundary of a rectangle*.  In another context I might call that a *line*, one with a few straight segments and a few circular arcs ... which is the conclusion you've already come to. But I think we've also come to the conclusion that *Mathematica* does not have an intrinsic graphic routine for that and you'll have to write your own.